# Nginx won't start since Ubuntu upgrade (16.04)

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, nginx

I have recently upgraded my Ubuntu server to the 16.04 release. Since then I can't start the nginx service.

Results `service nginx restart` :

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

What my system logs says (`cat /var/log/syslog`) :

```
May 20 17:03:53: Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
May 20 17:03:53: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
May 20 17:03:53: nginx.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/nginx: No such file or directory
May 20 17:03:53: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
May 20 17:03:53: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
May 20 17:03:53: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 20 17:03:53: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Results of `cat /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service` :

```
# Stop dance for nginx
# =======================
#
# ExecStop sends SIGSTOP (graceful stop) to the nginx process.
# If, after 5s (--retry QUIT/5) nginx is still running, systemd takes control
# and sends SIGTERM (fast shutdown) to the main process.
# After another 5s (TimeoutStopSec=5), and if nginx is alive, systemd sends
# SIGKILL to all the remaining processes in the process group (KillMode=mixed).
#
# nginx signals reference doc:
# http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html
#
[Unit]
Description=A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -s reload
# Use TERM instead of QUIT to prevent Nginx from leaving stale Unix socket and failing the next start (https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/753)
ExecStop=-/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry TERM/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid
# Give Passenger a chance to clean up before being killed by systemd.
ExecStop=/bin/sleep 1
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=mixed

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

There is indeed no file at `/usr/sbin/nginx`, so I tried `apt install nginx`, but here the result :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx : Depends: nginx-core (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-full (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-light (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-extras (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: nginx-core (< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-full (< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-light (< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-extras (< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Update 1 :**

Résults of `systemctl status nginx.service` after running `updatedb` :

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-05-20 17:41:49 CEST; 1min 30s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 11212 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 11210 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 20 17:41:48 ns3031916.ip-178-32-217.eu nginx[11212]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
May 20 17:41:48 ns3031916.ip-178-32-217.eu nginx[11212]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
May 20 17:41:48 ns3031916.ip-178-32-217.eu nginx[11212]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
May 20 17:41:49 ns3031916.ip-178-32-217.eu nginx[11212]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
May 20 17:41:49 ns3031916.ip-178-32-217.eu nginx[11212]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
May 20 17:41:49 ns3031916.ip-178-32-217.eu nginx[11212]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
May 20 17:41:49 ns3031916.ip-178-32-217.eu systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 20 17:41:49 ns3031916.ip-178-32-217.eu systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
May 20 17:41:49 ns3031916.ip-178-32-217.eu systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 20 17:41:49 ns3031916.ip-178-32-217.eu systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

As a newbie, I'm pretty lost in that mess and I realy need a bit of help.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Can you also run "updatedb" and then run "locate nginx". Sorry can't comment due to reputation. apt related errors have to be resolved separately.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.

After running `updatedb`, there is still a error message : `Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

But it's different from the last one. You can see the results of `systemctl status nginx.service` in **Update 1**

Comment: Problem solved here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/917147/nginx-wont-start-since-ubuntu-upgrade-16-04/917152#917152

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/917147/nginx-wont-start-since-ubuntu-upgrade-16-04/917152#917152

### Copy/paste of Thomas Ward's answer that solved my problem:

> So you've got two things which are in conflict and have led it seems
>   to the nginx binaries going away somehow:  Xenial repository version,
>   and the NGINX PPA.  As the maintainer of both, allow me to explain the
>   conflict.
>
> In Xenial, we released 1.10.0 just after release as an update.  This
>   update pushed us to a 'stable' branch but didn't have
>   dynamically-loadable modules built and made available.  This was due
>   to time but also build conflicts that arose during tests.  We
>   eventually got dynamic module support working, in Zesty.
>
> In the PPA, we've always cloned directly from Debian.  That means, we
>   always had Debian's 'dynamic module' support, which conflicted with
>   the Xenial packages and resulted in some installation and upgrade
>   conflicts.
>
> ---
>
> There's a small conflict here - you can't mix-and-match `nginx-core`
>   (which is the default flavor installed for the `nginx` package in
>   Ubuntu) and the PPAs, as it sometimes makes things disappearify.  The
>   problem here, then, is we need to remove the existing Ubuntu package
>   and then install from the PPA only.
>
> To resolve this, you'll first need to back up your nginx
>   configurations you want to keep for your sites.  That is, make a copy
>   of your /etc/nginx/sites-available/ directory somewhere else (even in
>   your user's home directory is fine, we just need a copy of the site
>   configurations).  As well, we'll need a backup of your website data,
>   so copy that somewhere else as well (NOT in the standard docroot, so
>   it doesn't get messed up).
>
> Once you make the copy, you'll have to remove the existing nginx
>   packages.  This can be done with the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get remove nginx nginx-common nginx-doc nginx-core nginx-full nginx-extras nginx-light
> ```
>
> Once that is complete, run `sudo apt-get update` again just to make
>   sure we have the most up to date version numberings.
>
> Then, install `nginx` from the PPA - `sudo apt-get install nginx
>   nginx-full nginx-common` should do this.
>
> You should no longer be getting failed to start errors.  Make sure
>   your site configurations are still in place, and didn't get
>   overwritten.  If they did, restore from the backups we took earlier of
>   the site config and the site data.  Otherwise, you're all set.